# Tensorflow, using trained network

Tags: tensorflow

I'm new to tensor flow, and I'm studying cifar10 example provided in tensorflow website.

I can follow the provided code to train a network and evaluate it, which says the trained network has the accuracy of ~84%.

However, when I feed images from cifar10 website to output the prediction, the accuracy is no way near the promised 84%. 
(I downloaded a few sample pics from https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html for testing)

During the training, I'm saving my weights and biases using:

```
tf.add_to_collection('vars', kernel1)
tf.add_to_collection('vars', biases1)
...
```

Then, once the training is complete, I load them by:

```
ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(FLAGS.checkpoint_dir)
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('.../model.ckpt-1000000.meta')
saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('.../'))
kernel1 = tf.get_collection('vars')[0]
kernel1 = sess.run(kernel1)
```

once all weights and biases are loaded, I can compute the output through convolution, pooling, and so on.

Would please someone can point out if there's anything wrong in this scheme?

Any help would be really appreciated

Regards,

Comment: Did you initialize a `Session` before using it? How did you do it? What's the error?

Comment: I initialized them using tf.global_variables_initializer(). I can compile and run the code. The problem is, I'm getting poor results when I manually feed png images....I've tested the trained network with 100 images, and the network only got 40 right.